# Can I deploy my video processing application on the cloud?

Tags: c++, azure, cloud, paas, iaas

I have a C++ application developed with OpenCV and Qt.

It communicates with a mobile application (Android and iOS).

It processes the video stream sent from the phone and return messages to the phone.

I want to deploy it on the cloud, so that I can access it anywhere from the internet.

Can I deploy this application on the cloud? I am completely beginner in cloud development.

Comment: Regarding 'easiest way to do this' - that's a matter of opinion/discussion. No single right answer, and unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: I removed 'easiest way to do this', you should remove the downvote.

Comment: The question is still off-topic: "How do I do this" - there isn't one way to do it. This would be appropriate for a discussion forum. There is great content on the Azure site explaining the various services at your disposal. It's a great place to start.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: I changed the question to be the most specific. You should remove your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++ rules out Azure PaaS options ([Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) and [Azure Cloud Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/)). So you'll need to leverage Iaas options ([Azure Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/), Virtual network) and deploy your code as usual.

This means, you'll:

- Register to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/)
- Provision a new Virtual Machine

  - selecting your OS, instance size, location, ...
- Copy your binaries to your new instance
- Open the network ports required by your application
- TEST!
- ...

Comment: Thanks, +1, very useful.

Comment: **This is not true.** Azure Cloud Services (web and worker roles) have no restriction around c++ or installation of software - they utilize stateless Windows Server VMs.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: you are very welcome to put your answer if you know the solution.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: I changed the question, you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be very tough and most probably impossible. But you can instead simply use Azure Media Services that can process your videos for online streaming and other very handy stuff.